# Blizzard Download: This download is not authorized

Tags: technical-issues, battle.net, starcraft

I'm on Windows 7. When I download Starcraft Anthology from the website and try to install it on my computer I get the error "This download is not Authorized" followed by "There was a problem authenticating your download. Please go to http://www.blizzard.com/account/ to start a new download."

I've tried Safe mode, and running it as administrator, and both at the same time. I tried downloading it in Safe Mode with Networking on Internet Explorer. I have tried redownloading the downloader. There's a timestamp encryption on it, so you can only use it the day you download it.

I have tried downloading it to a different folder. Both running the file from another folder, other than where it is currently, and extracting it to another folder than the one specified. I tried deleting the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USE​R\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Downlo​ader\
```

I get the error "This download is not Authorized" followed by "There was a problem authenticating your download. Please go to http://www.blizzard.com/account/ to start a new download."

Googled references:

[Battle.net Forum -Diablo 3 Not authorized](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4008090814?page=3)
[Battle.net Forum - Starcraft 2 Beta](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=23425639087)
[Battle.net Forum - Diablo 2](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=23767638005)
[Battle.net Forum - Starcraft 2](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=22418710582&sid=3000&pageNo=2)
[Battle.net Forum - Warcraft 3 + Addon](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=22050165773)
[Battle.net Forum --Starcraft Anthology](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=19820506061)
[Starcraft EU - Mac Support](http://blues.incgamers.com/Posts/9/1/35/799/114402/starcraft-ii-tournament-license-reminder)
[GamerTechTv - Blizzard Download issue](http://www.gamertechtv.com/2010/blizzard-download-issues-this-download-is-not-authorized/)
[WoW Blue - Error 3.3.3 not authorized](http://www.wowblues.com/eu/333-error-download-not-authorized-12947096652.html)

Comment: Have you been in touch with customer support?

Comment: Have you run the downloader in administrative?

Comment: Steinin: Battle.net - Web Issue (Ticket US34766046) Ender: I quote "I've tried Safe mode, and running in administrator mode and both at the same time. I tried downloading it in Safe Mode with Networking on Internet Explorer." and "I right click on the executable used to download the program and chose 'run as administrator'."

Comment: So you have opened a ticket. Guess you will have to wait. If you don't want to wait I'd recommend calling them to get the fastest response.

Comment: Why do you link to references to Diablo II, World of Warcraft, and Starcraft 2 if your asking about Starcraft?  have you tried the compatability mode on the installer?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with my legacy games downloads. I managed to make it work by keeping Internet Explorer open during the download.

Comment: Did you have this problem with the Blizzard installer, or something else?